# Existence of a table before an operation

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-insert, exists

I want to do a test on the existence of a table to do some thing like:

If (Table exists) then my operation will be an insert into Table

Else I will do :

```
 select * into Table from MySource
```

How could we perform this with SQL?

When I check just the existence of the table with:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table)
    print 'OK'
Else
    Print 'KO'
```

I don't get the KO when the table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('[Your Table]') IS NOT NULL)
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOK'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema' 
                     AND  TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable'))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'OK'
   ELSE

        PRINT 'KO'
    END
```

Comment: you missed the 'END` for the first `BEGIN` and also missed the `BEGIN` for the `ELSE` part

Comment: we don't get the KO